# Azure DevOps SSH Public Key expiration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, public-key

Can anyone advise if there is API to monitor Azure DevOps SSH Public Key expiration? Thanks!

Comment: I doubt there's an API like that.

Comment: Hi @HPLoh, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late update. I yet to test this out, will try the suggestion, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @HPLoh, you could try it and then kindly share the result here. If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We could not see the REST API in the Microsoft Doc.

As a workaround, we could capture the REST API via F12 or Fiddler. This is the API I got through F12.

REST API

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview
```

Request Body

```
{
  "contributionIds": [
    "ms.vss-admin-web.profile-sshpublickeys-view-data-provider"
  ],
  "dataProviderContext": {
    "properties": {
      "authorizationId": "{authorizationId}",
      "sourcePage": {
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_usersSettings/keys",
        "routeId": "ms.vss-admin-web.user-admin-hub-route",
        "routeValues": {
          "adminPivot": "keys",
          "controller": "ContributedPage",
          "action": "Execute",
          "serviceHost": "4719eefb-8e42-4e86-8ed0-8c960b7e4f74 ({Org name})"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can check whether the key has expired through the `isValid` field

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Vito,Sorry for the late. I tried to use the Firefox RestClient to run the post, https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview  (change the Org name to my organization name) , but it is not working. i can see the return Body . Could you advise how to run the post and capture the api return result? thank

Comment: Could you please share the return Body here?

Comment: Sorry, there was typo error on my previous comment. There is no return Body. Body is empty, nothing in the Body field.

Answer (score -1):

SSH Keys do not have an expired date so the question is irrelevant. SSH keys are used for [asymmetric cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) operations only. You probably get confused between x509 certificate and private/public keys.

The SSH public key is valid till the user account is active on Azure DevOPS or if the user deletes it as it's handled on the user profile level

Update: SSH keys do not expire but Azure DevOPS store the SSH keys for 5 years then you need to renew (not to say re-upload) it.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops

> Also note that SSH keys stored in Azure DevOps expire after five
> years. If your key expires, you may upload a new key or the same one
> to continue accessing Azure DevOps via SSH.

Comment: Go to Azure DevOps > User Settings > SSH Public Keys.  
The keys themselves might not, but those fields do have an expiration date.

Comment: Those fields are the "added date" not the expired date. However, following your comment, I double check MS docs, and I found the line in which they mentioned that they store the SSH keys for 5 years and then you need to re-upload it. So the SSH keys do not expire but Azure DevOPS SSH keys storage yes. I update my answer according to the MS docs.

Comment: I do have fields that say "Expiration Date". To the right of "Added Date".
And it is certainly interesting, because I have a key I made in 2021 that is valid until 2026, but the one I created just now has an expiration of just 1 year, not 5. I sent some feedback to the docs about this, but it also seems plausible that it might just be my company doing this.

Comment: As mentioned on MS docs (please see my updated answer... You can use the SAME ONE (=re-upload the same key in the Azure DevOPS SSH key storage). It means the SSH key does not expire. When you generate a SSH pair keys on your computer, it does not ask you to set an expired date. You have a company policy if you have an Expired Date column (which is not the default behaviour). You can try it on your computer, generate ssh keys, open the file with a notepad, and let me know if you can find an expired date. Do not confuse it with a SSH certificate which can have an optional validity period.